# Accessing Arraylist Items

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to access the items from `bookList` in the `onItemClickListener`. I want to access specific books and get specific items from them how to do this?

The code is :

```
// Creating volley request obj
final JsonArrayRequest bookrequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                hidePDialog();

                // Parsing json
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject obj =(JSONObject) response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Book book = new Book();
                        book.setTitle(obj.getString("BTitle"));
                        book.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("BCoverpath"));
                        book.setAuthor(obj.getString("BAuthor"));
                        book.setEdition(obj.getString("BEdition"));
                        book.setCategory(obj.getString("Bcategory"));
                        book.setLanguage(obj.getString("BLanguage"));
                        book.setDescription(obj.getString("BDescription"));
                        book.setCover(obj.getString("BCover"));
                        book.setOwner(obj.getString("UserFN"));

                        // adding book to books array
                        bookList.add(book);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                // notifying list adapter about data changes
                // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();
            }
        }
);

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(bookrequest);

// setting an onItem click listener in order to open the view book activity
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2, long arg3) {
        bookname=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
        Bauthor=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.author)).getText().toString();
        Bedition=((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.edition)).getText().toString();

        // intent to take the viewbook activity as its next dextination
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewBook.class);

        // putting the name of the book with the inten extra package to use it as
        // a key to retrieve the book info from the database and display it
        i.putExtra("bookname",bookname);
        i.putExtra("category",Bcategory);
        i.putExtra("Bauthor",Bauthor);
        i.putExtra("Bedition",Bedition);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

I tried many methods and most of them end with an Out of bound exception and index out of bounds.

Comment: What is the relevance of all the 400 lines of code you've posted? How do they attempt to solve or interfere with the issue you've posted? If they don't, why have you included them? Please remove them. Read the help center, particularly on how to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: i simplified the code :) any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within `onItemClick(...)` you have access to the position of the item that was clicked and the source of the items so you can use that information to get the actual item that was clicked.

I renamed the parameters to `onItemClick()` to give them a more descriptive name and assumed you have matching getter methods for the fields in `Book`.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Book b = bookList.get(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(Romance.this, ViewBook.class)
            .putExtra("bookname", b.getTitle())
            .putExtra("category", b.getCategory())
            .putExtra("Bauthor", b.getAuthor())
            .putExtra("Bedition", b.getEdition);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot George , imagine 7 hrs of coding and at last you saved me lol i feel stupid , thanks alot again :)